# horizontal chained select with jquery

Tags: chained-select

I found an example online, but I couldn't get list items horizontally like [here](http://download.remysharp.com/ebay_categories.gif), whatever I did, they came vertically. Any help is appreciated. The example is [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the style of each scroll menu to "display: inline-block" they should show up horizontally. Here is a simple example with divs...

```
<div style="background-color: black;display: inline-block;width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="background-color: black;display: inline-block;width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="background-color: black;display: inline-block;width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: tried with "display: inline" and it worked, thank you so much!